# "The resource identifier of the KeyVault parameter '' is invalid" error during ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I have a template (param+template file).
Param file has the following code:

```
  "sqlServerAdminLoginPassword": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, parameters('keyvaultRG'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('KeyVaultName'))]"
        },
        "secretName": "sqlAdminPassword"
      }
```

During the deployment (from VS2017) the following error occurs:

```
00:17:22 - 
00:17:22 - VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Creating Deployment" on target "XXXXXXXX".
00:17:23 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 12:17:23 AM - Error: Code=KeyVaultParameterReferenceInvalidResourceId; 
00:17:23 - Message=The resource identifier of the KeyVault parameter 'sqlAdminPassword' is invalid. Please specify the value following 
00:17:23 - 'subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vaultName}' 
00:17:23 - format. See https://aka.ms/arm-keyvault for usage details.
00:17:23 - At ######################
00:17:23 - ###\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:108 char:5
00:17:23 - +     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
00:17:23 - +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
00:17:23 -     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
00:17:23 -     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
00:17:23 -    loymentCmdlet
00:17:23 -  
00:17:23 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
00:17:23 - At ######################
00:17:23 - ###\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:108 char:5
00:17:23 - +     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
00:17:23 - +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
00:17:23 -     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
00:17:23 -     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
00:17:23 -    loymentCmdlet
00:17:23 -  
00:17:24 - 
00:17:24 - Template deployment returned the following errors:
00:17:24 - 12:17:23 AM - Error: Code=KeyVaultParameterReferenceInvalidResourceId; Message=The resource identifier of the KeyVault parameter 'sqlAdminPassword' is invalid. Please specify the value following 'subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vaultName}' format. See https://aka.ms/arm-keyvault for usage details.
00:17:24 - The deployment validation failed
00:17:24 - 
00:17:24 - 
00:17:24 - Deploying template using PowerShell script failed.
00:17:24 - Tell us about your experience at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691202
```

According to the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-a-secret-with-dynamic-id) article and the [following](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/master/azure-resource-manager/keyvaultparameter/sqlserver-dynamic-id.json) template file I should be able to use the same construction, however, it doesn't work.

What can be wrong here?

P.S. Indeed, the resources, and parameters (like keyvaultRG or KeyVaultName) are present (and exist).

P.P.S. The [following](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/2036) and [following](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2939) issues exist on Github but still unasnwered\unassigned...

Upd:

Template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appServicePlanName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "workerSize": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "skuCode": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "SQLserverName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sqlServerAdminLogin": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sqlServerAdminLoginPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "sqlDatabaseName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "edition": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "collation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "maxSizeBytes": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sampleName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "zoneRedundant": {
      "type": "bool"
    },
    "siteName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "appType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "KeyVaultName": {
      "type": "string"
    },    
    "mailAccount": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "mailPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
     "keyvaultRG": {
      "type": "string"      
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
        "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('workerSize')]"
      },
      "sku": {
        "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
        "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "name": "[parameters('SQLserverName')]",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqlServerAdminLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('sqlServerAdminLoginPassword')]",
        "version": "12.0"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "type": "firewallrules",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('SQLserverName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('SQLserverName'),'/',parameters('sqlDatabaseName'))]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('SQLserverName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "edition": "[parameters('edition')]",
            "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
            "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxSizeBytes')]",
            "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]",
            "sampleName": "[parameters('sampleName')]",
            "zoneRedundant": "[parameters('zoneRedundant')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('appServicePlanName'))]": "empty"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('siteName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "siteConfig": {
          "alwaysOn": true,
          "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
          "httpsOnly": true,
          "connectionStrings": [
            {
              "name": "defaultConnection",
              "ConnectionString": "[concat(concat('Data Source=tcp:' ,reference(concat(parameters('SQLserverName')),'2015-05-01-preview').fullyQualifiedDomainName ,',1433;'),concat('Initial Catalog=',parameters('sqlDatabaseName'),';'),concat('User Id=',concat(parameters('sqlServerAdminLogin')),'@',reference(concat(parameters('sqlServerName')), '2015-05-01-preview').fullyQualifiedDomainName,';'),concat('Password=',parameters('sqlServerAdminLoginPassword'),';'))]",
              "type": "SQLAzure"
            }
          ],
          "appSettings": []
        },
        "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('appServicePlanName'))]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "logs",
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "applicationLogs": {
              "fileSystem": {
                "level": "Verbose"
              }
            },
            "httpLogs": {
              "fileSystem": {
                "retentionInMb": 100,
                "retentionInDays": 90,
                "enabled": true
              }
            },
            "failedRequestsTracing": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "detailedErrorMessages": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },

  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

Param

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appServicePlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "AppSvcPlan"
    },
    "workerSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "0"
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "Standard"
    },
    "skuCode": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "S1"
    },
    "SQLserverName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "SQLSrv"
    },
    "sqlServerAdminLogin": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "dbuser"
    },
    "sqlServerAdminLoginPassword": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "[resourceId(parameters('keyvaultRG'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('KeyVaultName'))]"
        },
        "secretName": "sqlAdminPassword"
      }
    },
    "sqlDatabaseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "SQLDB"
    },
    "edition": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "Standard"
    },
    "collation": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    },
    "maxSizeBytes": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "268435456000"
    },
    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "S3"
    },
    "sampleName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": ""
    },
    "zoneRedundant": {
      "type": "bool",
      "value": false
    },
    "siteName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "AppName"
    },
    "appType": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "web"
    },
    "KeyVaultName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "keyvault"
    },
    "mailAccount": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "[resourceId(parameters('keyvaultRG'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('KeyVaultName'))]"
        },
        "secretName": "mailAccount"
      }
    },
    "mailPassword": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "[resourceId(parameters('keyvaultRG'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('KeyVaultName'))]"
        },
        "secretName": "mailPassword"
      }
    },
    "keyvaultRG": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "KeyVaultRG"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error clearly says: `KeyVaultParameterReferenceInvalidResourceId`

First of all, i'd shorten the reference:

```
"[resourceId(parameters('keyvaultRG'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('KeyVaultName'))]"
```

No point in specifying subscription if its the same. And my second point would be to ask you to provide the template you are using and parameters file, because the articles you reference are using nested template to achieve that, not parameters file. Also you should check your Azure Powershell version and update it.

Probably not use VS2017 to deploy it as well.
Another thing that can mess this up - kv permissions (this doesnt look like your case, but...) you need to enable KV for template deployments.

ok. it appears you cannot use expressions in KV id when its in parameters file. 2 workarounds:

1. use powershell to construct resourceId and put it in parameters file
2. use nested deployments, you can use resourceId there.

[image]

Comment: I've updated the question with template & param files. Excluded subscription reference. AzureRM version is the latest available. Deploy from POSH console produces the same error.

Comment: did you enable it for deployment?

Comment: Yes indeed, all 3 special permissions are checked

Comment: okay, after digging a bit here, it seems that you cannot use `resourceId()` in parameters file, but you can in a nested template

Comment: check this example: https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/_arm/parent.json

Comment: Can you link your findings? (reference)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174547/discussion-between-sergey-and-4c74356b41).

Comment: This link was extremely helpful to me in working out how I had to refactor my template to make things work. Essentially you must have a static string to look up the key vault ID, and MS seem to recommend you do that by calculating the variables in the parent template and then simply using those statically provided values in the child template. Note that they avoid using subscription().id and resourceGroup().name by using these as _default vaules_ in their reference template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter